# How to name grid areas using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, grid

What I've trieds (the element 'backspace' is just a normal div):

```
const backspace = document.querySelector(".backspace");

backspace.style.gridArea = backspace.classList.value;
```

Then when I log the value of the class list it gives:

```
backspace
```

But when I log the grid area it gives:

```
backspace / backspace / backspace / backspace
```

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your HTML markup as well? This will help others to understand more context behind the problem.

Comment: The querySelector returns the first html element with the class .backspace.
The value of classList is the value of the html element's classes, which is "backspace".
You are setting backspace.style.gridArea = backspace